# How to get gamepad joystick position on Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

Currently, I'm using the `ContextActionService` for my keyboard, mouse & gamepad button related events. However, for my *steering*, I want to use the position of the joystick on the controller.

I've found multiple ways to find the mouse's location, which I don't want to use at the moment, but no way to directly get the position of the gamepad joystick. If there is a way, I can't find where it says about it in the documentation. There's pressing it *down*, as in *pressing it*, but nothing about it's position

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the joystick positions, you need to use ContextActionService to get the InputObject for the gamepad. The tilt of the joysticks is stored on the `Position` property of the object. The [Gamepad docs](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/input/gamepad) have a pretty good walkthrough for it.

Try something like this in a LocalScript:

```lua
local ContextActionService = game:GetService("ContextActionService")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local gamepad = Enum.UserInputType.Gamepad1
if not UserInputService:GetGamepadConnected(gamepad) then
    warn("No gamepad detected!")
    return
end

local function handleInput(actionName : string, inputState : Enum.UserInputState, inputObject : InputObject)
    if actionName == "MoveStick1" then
        -- do something to handle the left joystick input
        local moveVector : Vector3 = inputObject.Position
        
    elseif actionName == "MoveStick2" then
        -- do something to handle the right joystick input
        local lookVector : Vector3 = inputObject.Position
    end
end

ContextActionService:BindAction("MoveStick1", handleInput, false, Enum.KeyCode.Thumbstick1)
ContextActionService:BindAction("MoveStick2", handleInput, false, Enum.KeyCode.Thumbstick2)
```

To better see the values, I scaled the Position vector by 100, rounded the value, and put each dimension into a TextLabel.

[image]

In this example ...

- the Left Joystick is in the lower right quadrant
- the Right Joystick is roughly in the middle left

Raw inputs from the joystick range from [-1, 1] on the X and Y axis. I don't know why the values are packed into a Vector3 and not a Vector2.

Comment: Really detailed response! I did see there was a Keycode for the thumbstick, but I didn't know how to grab it, so thanks for that!